# Nested includes in Pug drop block content in wrong spot

Tags: pug

I'm trying to setup the FE for a web application using Pug and I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm starting to wonder if Pug is capable of achieving this effect. I need to have a very modular approach to how the final page will be built, so here's what I've got. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Page.pug

```
extends ../../../components/Project/Views/Common/Standard

block main
    include ../../../components/Project/Views/Grid/1ColumnLayout/_1Column
        block prepend singleColumn
            .demo
                p Single Column
    include ../../../components/Project/Views/Grid/2ColumnLayouts/_2Column
        block append twoColumnLeft
            .demo
                p Left Column
        block prepend twoColumnRight
            .demo
                p Right Column
```

Standard.pug

```
extends ../Shared/_Layout.pug

block content
    header
        block header
            include ../Common/_Header
    main
        .container
            block main
    footer
        block footer
```

_1Column.pug

```
.row
    .col-12
        block singleColumn
```

_2Column.pug

```
.row
    .col-12.col-lg-6
        block twoColumnLeft
    .col-12.col-lg-6
        block twoColumnRight
```

My expectation would be that I have see "Single Column" printed in effectively a full-width container and "Left Column" and "Right Column" in the next row each in a 1/2 width column. However, the rendered HTML has the content from both blocks - "block twocolumnleft" and "block twocolumnright" - being output as if it was all in "block twocolumnright".

Page.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="demo">
            <p>Left Column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="demo">
            <p>Right Column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is a known behaviour. In the pug source code you can find [this](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/blob/48c69c95fa636147bc5b79e0a97a2672e3a6f31c/packages/pug-linker/index.js#L100). Correct me if I am wrong, pug is collecting the `append` and `prepend` childs and throw it to the last block name.

You can solve it with `mixins`. [pug docs - mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html)

Page.pug

```
extends Standard

block main
    include _1Column
        prepend singleColumn
            .demo
                p Single Column
    include _2Column
    +_2Column({
        left: '<p>Left Column</p>', 
        right: '<p>Right Column</p>'
    })
```

_2Column.pug

```
mixin _2Column(markup)
    .row
        .col-12.col-lg-6
            | !{markup.left}
        .col-12.col-lg-6
            | !{markup.right}
```

(I have shorten your pathnames)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. If it works, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I updated. In Page.pug `include _2Column` was twice.